# Odoo Python 2.7 Encoding utf8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to create a unicode string out of several fields. I do:

```
my_unicode_text = u' '.join((u'ID ',str(order_line.product_id.id),u' | [',order_line.product_id.code,u'] ',str(order_line.product_id.name),u' | ',str(order_line.product_uom_qty),u'<br/>')).encode('utf-8').strip())
```

But I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd3' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I guess I am not correctly using join / str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encode` is used to go from `unicode` to `str` not the inverse, means converting `unicode` to `bytes` (`str` in python 2.x):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = u'aller â'
print(type(s))
print(type(s.encode('utf-8')))  # convert to str but using utf-8 codec
print(s + str(1))  # unicode + str == unicode
print(str(s))  # generate an exception because its using `ascii` codec by default
```

so in your example product name is all ready a `utf-8` `unicode` no need to convert it at all just convert non string object like Integers, Floats.

```
my_unicode_text = u' '.join(
    (u'ID ',
     str(order_line.product_id.id),  # Integer
     u' | [',
     order_line.product_id.code,
     u'] ',
     order_line.product_id.name,  # utf-8 uncide (database encoding)
     u' | ',
     str(order_line.product_uom_qty),  # floats
     u'<br/>'))
```

but instead of using join use string formating and manually convert value:

```
my_unicode_text = u'ID {order_line.product_id.id} | [{order_line.product_id.code}] ' \
              u'{order_line.product_id.name} | {order_line.product_uom_qty}<br/>'.format(order_line=order_line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you replace the join with format:

```
class Product_id:
    def __init__(self, id, code, name):
        self.id, self.code, self.name = id, code, name

class Order_line:
    def __init__(self, product_id, product_uom_qty):
        self.product_id, self.product_uom_qty = product_id, product_uom_qty


order_line = Order_line(Product_id(42, 6789, u'\N{greek small letter beta}eer'), 6)

s = unicode.format(u'ID {order_line.product_id.id} | [{product_id.code}] {product_id.name} | {order_line.product_uom_qty}<br/>', order_line=order_line, product_id=order_line.product_id)

print s
```